# Wordpress Development: Set caching header for asset request

Tags: php, wordpress

I develop a WordPress plugin and i try to set caching headers for a specific GET request triggered by a script tag included in the HTML.

The URL of the requests looks like this:
http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/js/my-script.js

My idea was to somehow 'intercept' the GET request within my WordPress plugin code by using the 'add_action' method provided by WordPress.

I wrote a simple code snippet to test whether the plugin can see the GET request or not:

```
function handle_get_request($query) {
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'handle_request' );
```

Unfortunately the plugin only sees the navigate (HTML) request and not the GET request. Is there a way to see GET requests done within the HTML?

Comment: If this is a normal request for a static asset, then WordPress does not even get involved here – the WordPress default routing lets requests for any physically existing files / folders pass through unchanged. Why would you need to set a non-caching header for a static file in the first place?

Comment: The content of the javascript file changes e.g. when the admin is logged in. I want to ensure that no browser decides to cache the response because of missing cache-control header.

Comment: _“The content of the javascript file changes e.g. when the admin is logged in.”_ - sounds like a terrible idea already … If you have two different _static_ scripts for normal users/guests, and the admin - then you should switch between script sources (two different files, two different URLs), rather than the script content. If you need to supply different sets of _data_ for your JS code to work on, then you should rather be using `wp_add_inline_script` for that to begin with.

Comment: Among others, the script includes JSON with a list of URLs (needed for the configuration of the plugin). The current version of the plugin inlines the script and there where several customers complaning that URLs  contained within this script are crawled by Web crawlers. That is why I want to get rid of inline scripting.

Comment: So not functionality any non-admin user ever needs to see? Well then embed it for admin users only in the first place, the web crawlers are not going to log in as one of those …

Comment: The information of the JSON is required for both, admin and non-admin users.

Comment: _“and there where several customers complaning that URLs contained within this script are crawled by Web crawlers. That is why I want to get rid of inline scripting”_ - I wouldn’t be to sure that fixes this issue in the first place … But anyway, embed a random value or the current time stamp as a URL parameter in the URL you are using to embed this script file then, that is easier and works better than any caching headers.

Comment: I'll consult with my team about this. Thank you very much for your help.